# Laravel Sanctum - user two laravel for microservice (401 "Unauthenticated.")(Solved)

Tags: laravel, microservices, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

I Have two project of laravel and one of them have sanctum.and I wrote a middleware for another laravel project.

My middlware:

```
   $url = 'http://localhost/v1/management/auth/me';

   $suepackAuth = Http::withToken(
        ltrim($request->header('Authorization'),'Bearer ')
    )->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json', 'secret' => '65dsa156sda15dsa1dsa65'])->get($url);

    echo ($suepackAuth->body());
    if (!$suepackAuth->ok())
        throw new AuthenticationException();

    // auth()->login();
    return $next($request);
```

when I excute upper code response unauthorize
but when I call with postman call `http://localhost/v1/management/auth/me`, worked fine.

for more description
when i start project with `php artisan serve` and set `$url` 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000 my microservice work.

Kernel project in localhost:

```
     /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

[image: Have Problem]
[image: Work prject]

Comment: I found a problem my env override another env, but I don know why
I use mamp pro

Comment: I found solution after 4 hours
use: individual php version for every host
in php language